# Why do I get this No module named 'pygame in Spyder even after installing pip intall pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

I'm a very beginner python programmer.
I installed pygame however when I import pygame in spyder, it doesn't work.
[pip install pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afEM0.png)

The following message prompts.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Below is what I wrote so far

import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WITH, HEIGHT))

def main():

```
run = True

while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #end this while loop
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`py -m pip install pygame`
or

`python3 -m pip install pygame`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re a user on your computer without elevated privileges which belong to the admin. If the prompt showed an error while installing pygame, it means you do not have the required permissions.
Try to install pygame with the  `pip install --user pygame`